# UWP application doesn't start without debugger

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019, windows-10-iot-core

I have a UWP app which works fine in Visual Studio 2017. Since I updated to Visual Studio 2019 the Application works fine while debugging with Visual Studio. The creation of the App Bundle finishes without problems, and the App works well on an X86 or X64 System. But if I install on a Raspberry Pi (ARM) the App won't start. It is showing the startup screen forever.

Is there any way to narrow down the Problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows running on ARM, but if it has the Event Viewer, I would check there under "Windows Logs" -> "Application" and see if there are any relevant error messages.

Comment: Which build of Windows IoT Core was running on your device? And which target version was selected in the project? When the app starts, you can use [device portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal) to view the performance of the device.In addition, is there any action when the app starts. You can use [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/appdeployment) to troubleshoot the issue.